# Using PowerBI tiles in another application

Tags: powerbi

having obtained a list of dashboards and then the tiles associated with those dashboards , the links that I get back do not seem to work I am left with a spinning indicator when I try to view in the browser IE or Edge.

url format https://app.powerbi.com/embed?dashboardId=< some UUID>&tileId=< some UUID>

has this worked for others..

Answer (score 0):

If you get an infinite spinning wheel, it's usually because you did not provide authentication credentials needed to load the tile.  Each tile you render needs to be rendered on behalf of a specific user and pass their user credentials. Your page needs to obtain and pass an access token to the iFrame after you instantiate the iFrame (i.e. setting src='foo' is not enough).  You need to follow that with a post message containing an access token for the user wishing to view the tile.

You can read our blog post (see **Integrating tiles into Applications**) here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2015/09/23/power-bi-api-updates-roundup.aspx

We have a sample that shows how to do it as well:
https://github.com/PowerBI/Integrate-a-tile-into-an-app

Let me know if you still can't get it to work after following all the steps.

Comment: I actually it is this demo app that I am using, I manually set the token in the onLoad method of the first page accessTokenTextbox.Text = token; as the standard auth method was not working correctly, I used the code for the getting started demo for this and it seems to work a treat.. 

The token is not accessible from that text box value in the iframe.. I will take another look at it..

Comment: Perhaps you're not wait for the iFrame to load before sending it the accessToken? The sample is designed so that the host page sends the token to the iFrame (not the other way around). So you do need to ensure the token is passed. Best is to look at the .js code in the browser's debugger to see how it's done.  ASP.Net web apps have esoteric structure so the .js code is in Site.Master (https://github.com/PowerBI/Integrate-a-tile-into-an-app/blob/master/PBIWebApp/Site.Master).